# Getting an Error with JavaFX trying to make a new dialog and bind a progress bar in it to a worker

Tags: java, javabeans, javafx

I followed the advice of another answer on StackOverflow [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx?lq=1), but when I attempted to run my program, I got a null pointer exception.

I have code that makes a new worker and starts a thread and then attempts to show a profiler dialog.  However, this dialog does not open properly.

```
@FXML
private void profilePDBFoldertoCSVAction(ActionEvent e) {
PDBProfilerOperator worker = new PDBProfilerOperator();
FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
DirectoryChooser dc = new DirectoryChooser();
Stage s = new Stage();
worker.setPdbsdirectory(dc.showDialog(s));
worker.setOutputCSV(fc.showSaveDialog(s));
Thread th = new Thread(worker);
th.setDaemon(true);
th.start();
worker.showProfilerDialog(worker);
}
```

The showProfilerDialog is the following:

```
public Stage showProfilerDialog(PDBProfilerOperator operator) {
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/pdpro/gui/dialogues/dataset/ProfilingProgress.fxml"));
ProfilingProgressController controller = loader.<ProfilingProgressController>getController();
controller.initProgress(operator);
Parent root = null;
try {
  root = (Parent) loader.load();
} catch (IOException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(PDPro.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.setTitle("Profiling Progress");
stage.show();
return stage;
}
```

And the initProgress is the following:

```
public void initProgress(PDBProfilerOperator operator) {
  this.profilingFiles.progressProperty().bind(operator.progressProperty());
}
```

I get a NullPointerException when attempting to run the initProgress since the controller remains Null.  How do I fix this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code in my previous answer to [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx?lq=1) was incorrect - the fxml must be loaded before retrieving the controller from the FXMLLoader.  I updated the incorrect code in the answer.

To apply the same fix to Kylamus' code:

```
public Stage showProfilerDialog(PDBProfilerOperator operator) {
  try {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
      getClass().getResource(
        "/pdpro/gui/dialogues/dataset/ProfilingProgress.fxml"
      )
    );
    Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();

    ProfilingProgressController controller = 
      loader.<ProfilingProgressController>getController();
    controller.initProgress(operator);

    Stage stage = new Stage(new Scene(root));
    stage.setTitle("Profiling Progress");
    stage.show();

    return stage;
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(PDPro.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }

  return null;
}
```

---

There is an executable [sample](https://gist.github.com/4631319) where I make use of similar constructs in the answer to [How can I use a variable from another Controller in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511016/how-can-i-use-a-variable-from-another-controller-in-javafx)

---

Other possible reasons which can cause failure to load fxml files are the ones below (although none of these were the actual reason in this case):

1. Your fxml is malformed => open it in [SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html) and see if SceneBuilder notes any errors.
2. Your fxml isn't where it's supposed to be => Does `getClass().getResource("/pdpro/gui/dialogues/dataset/ProfilingProgress.fxml")` return null?
3. Your fxml does not reference your controller => see [how to reference a controller](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers).

Comment: My FXML seems to have 0 errors and opens in SceneBuilder 1.0 and 1.1.
getClass() doesn't return a null and a System Out Print on it returned this: jar:file:/X:/Work/PDPro/pdpro/dist/pdpro.jar!/pdpro/gui/dialogues/dataset/ProfilingProgress.fxml
My FXML references the controller here: fx:controller="pdpro.gui.dialogues.dataset.ProfilingProgressController" and SceneBuilder recognizes the different methods in it in dropdown menus.

Comment: Is there anything else I should test for?!

Thanks, JewelSea!