# How can I use a variable from another Controller in JavaFX

Tags: java, controller, javafx-2, javafx, viewcontroller

I have two scenes Login.fxml and MainView.fxml and two diferent controllers LoginController.java and MainViewControler.java

In LoginController I do the whole process to login and get the value of JSessionID and store it in a object, like below:

```
loginGateway = loginGateway(gateway);
```

Now in MainViewController I need to use the this object (loginGateway) to getJSessionID and make other requests to the server. But how can I acess this object in another Controller Class (MainViewController.java) ????

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update 2023**

As noted in the referenced question:

- [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx)

An alternate solution to that presented here is to use MVC, similar to as documented in:

- [Applying MVC With JavaFx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx)

The solution presented here is still perfectly OK, but you might have a bit more flexibility (and a bit more complexity) by adopting the MVC approach instead.

---

Use a variation on the solution in [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx).

Setup a `LoginManager` which has a reference to both the `LoginController` and the `MainViewController`.

1. The `loginManager` creates a login screen using the `loginController` and passes a reference to itself to the `loginController`.
2. When login has passed, the `loginController` notifies the `loginManager` of the login `sessionID`.
3. The `loginManager` can then create a `MainViewController`, passing the `mainViewController` the `sessionID` and replacing the scene contents with the main view.

Here is a link to [some sample code](https://gist.github.com/4631319) to demonstrate this approach.
[image: login screen]
[image: mainview screen]

Comment: Did you test it? Cause I had to fix somethings to build it, but still don't running. For exemple:

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader("mainview.fxml");
MainViewController controller = loader.MainViewController>getController();
controller.initSessionID(sessionID);
scene.setRoot(loader.load());

I think should be:

Comment: FXMLLoader loader = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainView.fxml"));
MainViewController controller = (MainViewController) loader.<MainViewController>getController();
controller.initSessionID(sessionID);
scene.setRoot(loader.load());

Even though the last line scene.setRoot(loader.load()); continues to show something wrong (method setRoot in class Scene cannot be applied to given types; required: Parent, found: Object, reason: actual argument Object cannot be converted to Parent by method invocation conversion)

Can you help me one more time?? Please.

Comment: I just pasted an uncompiled code snippet to show the general approach.  I will run everything through a compiler with fxml files and everything to generate new version you could just copy and paste to execute - it will take me some time though.  I'll post back when it's done.

Comment: Replaced original psuedo code with a link to an externally hosted compilable sample.

Comment: @jewelsea i find your source examples really really helpfull! :) thx for sharing

Comment: Another approach (similar, but with some differences) [here](https://gist.github.com/james-d/bae73788a9b881cf9358cbf2d842f554).