# How to pass object to 2nd window in JavaFX?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, controller, fxml

I have seen this question asked a few times but unfortunately I couldn't get my problem solved from the given answers. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19866175/how-can-i-pass-value-from-one-page-to-another-in-java-fx) suits me best, easy to understand.

I have 1 main, 2 controllers(primary, secondary) and 2 fxml(primary,secondary) files. This is how I open my second window from my primary controller:

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonOpenSecondWindow(ActionEvent event) {

    try{
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("SecondWindow.fxml"));
        Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL); 
        stage.setTitle("Second Window");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));  
        stage.show();
      }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This works fine, all I want above is to add my object(s) somewhere in the parenthesises above.

Maybe:

```
root1.setMyObjects(object1, object2);
```

I tried to convert my code to the answer I liked but when I create a constructor for the secondary Controller the `Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();` line always fails(But it works when called from the primary controller). I do have an `initialize();` method as well in secondary controller. I tried with constructor, without constructor, putting constructor parts into `initialize();` but none worked... I would be glad if you can give a hand.

Answer (score 0):

You should use global variables in first controller, and get variables in second controller.