# Calling method once window has loaded

Tags: java, javafx, methods, popup

I'm having some difficulty with loading a method once my popup window has loaded. I've gotten the code to work, but only once you click a button. I'm new to JavaFX, this is the first thing I've written with it.

I've posted the signUp Controller and PopUp FXML. The issue is when you click Enter after entering your username, a popup box should appear with the username and your random 4 digit code. I can't get my code to change userShown and passShown to the username you entered and your random digits, though it will change if I assign a button to do this action by calling setLabels().

The code is a bit messy as I've been mucking around trying to figure out ways to get this to work, so there may be bits that aren't needed.

There may also be a lot of imports due to my many failed attempts at trying to get this to work. I know this isn't the way you should store a username/code, but it's more of a mini system to stop family members using not your account. It's not being distributed just a sort of test to learn JavaFX.

signUp Controller:

```java
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import org.omg.CORBA.INITIALIZE;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
    
public class signUpController {
    
    @FXML
    private TextField userName;
    @FXML
    private Label userShown;
    @FXML
    private Label passShown;
    
    Writer write = new Writer();
    
    static public String uName;
    static public int uCode;
    int number = (int)( Math.random() * 9999);
    static boolean done = false;
    
    public void homeButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
        Parent signUpParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Splash.fxml"));
        Scene signUpScene = new Scene(signUpParent);
        
        //This line gets the Stage information
        // Make it a node type object -> get source -> get the scene -> get the window -> window = window(stage)
        Stage window = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        
        window.setScene(signUpScene);
        window.centerOnScreen();
        window.show();
        window.setResizable(false);
    }
    
    // Passing Login Details to Writer to Write to Users.txt
    public void signUpButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
        // To make sure number is higher than 999
        if (number < 1000) {
            number += 1000;
        }
        uCode = number;
        uName = userName.getText();
        // Write Username/Code to Txt Doc
        System.out.println(userName.getText() + number);
        write.writeStart(userName.getText(),number);

        loginPopUp();
        setLabels();

        if (done == true) {
        homeButton(event);
        done = false;
        }
        
        // Reset Number
        number = (int)( Math.random() * 9999);
    }
    
    // Giving Login Details
    public void loginPopUp()throws IOException   {
        Stage window2 = new Stage(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        Parent loginPopUpParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("loginPopUp.fxml"));
        Scene loginPopUpScene = new Scene(loginPopUpParent);
            
        window2.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        window2.setScene(loginPopUpScene);
        window2.setResizable(false);
        window2.centerOnScreen();
        window2.show();
                
        done = true;
    }
    
    private void setLabels() {
        userShown.setText(uName);
        passShown.setText(Integer.toString(uCode));
    }

    public void close(ActionEvent event){
         Stage window2 = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
       window2.close();
    }
}
```

Sign Up FXML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="signUpController">
   <top>
      <ImageView fitHeight="96.0" fitWidth="600.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <image>
            <Image url="@Hangman.png" />
         </image>
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets left="20.0" top="50.0" />
         </BorderPane.margin>
      </ImageView>
   </top>
   <center>
      <VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="15.0">
         <children>
            <Label text="Please Enter Your Chosen Username">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <TextField fx:id="userName" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="192.0" promptText="Username" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#signUpButton" text="Enter" />
            <Button layoutX="288.0" layoutY="171.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#homeButton" text="Back" />
         </children>
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets top="20.0" />
         </BorderPane.margin>
      </VBox>
   </center>
   <bottom>
      <Pane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Pane layoutX="279.0" layoutY="8.0" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

Login Pop Up FXML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="267.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="signUpController">
   <children>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Username:" wrappingWidth="122.45364984856826">
               <font>
                  <Font size="26.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <Label fx:id="userShown" text="Name Here">
               <font>
                  <Font size="26.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Password Code:" wrappingWidth="183.45364984856826">
               <font>
                  <Font size="26.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <Label fx:id="passShown" text="Code Here">
               <font>
                  <Font size="26.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#close" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="53.0" text="Close">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets right="10.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
         </children>
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets />
         </VBox.margin>
      </HBox>
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="50.0" left="15.0" top="50.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

Any help would be vastly appreciated, if there's any guides or tutorials that are great for teaching JavaFX could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/ Go thorugh this tutorial and you will have a decent start into JavaFX

Comment: Could you not use the stock [`Dialog`](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/)?

Comment: It's pretty bad practice to have two different FXMLs have the same controller, I think you may need to restructure how you're doing things.

Comment: I've been going through the link provided by JT 1114, I've noticed how many errors I have made and how my code isn't laid/setup correctly. I'm going through the tutorial then rebuilding. :)

Comment: [`Here`](https://github.com/sedj601/SimpleLoginFx) is a code example you can follow that shows how to use the stock [`Dialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html)/[`Alert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html).

Comment: Similar question seems to be: [How can I use a variable from another Controller in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511016/how-can-i-use-a-variable-from-another-controller-in-javafx).  Definitely, as stated by MMAdams, you should never try to have two different FXML files backed by the same controller, a controller per FXML file is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Title indicates you want this sort of thing.

It's a bit laborious but this will do the equivalent of the html onLoad thing, code goes off once scene is loaded and showing.

```
Stage stage;
FXMLLoader  loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("./file.fxml"));
Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
stage.setScene(scene);

// Create event handler
stage.setOnShown((WindowEvent event) -> {
    // After show code
}

stage.show();
```

Comment: beware: your resource lookup is wrong!